# How to save data using ajax request in Laravel version 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, popup

My ajax call:

```
$('#password_change_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var saveThis = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ url('/changepassword') }}",
        data: $(saveThis).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#password_change_form").trigger("reset");
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}),
```

My Controller method:

```
public function changepassword(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();
    $request_data = $request->All();
    $validator = $this->admin_credential_rules($request_data);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $errors = json_decode($errors);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $errors
        ], 422);
    } else {

        $current_password = $user->password;
        if(md5($request_data['password']) == $current_password) {
            $user_id = $user->id;
            $obj_user = User::find($user_id);
            $obj_user->password = md5($request_data['new_password']);
            $obj_user->save();

            $msg = "password has been changed";
            return response()->json(array('change_password'=> $msg), 200);
        } else {
            $error = array('error' => array('Heslo, kterÃ© jste zadali, je neplatnÃ©.'));
            return response()->json([
                'modal_message_danger' , "Heslo, které jste zadali, je neplatné.",
                'message' => $error
            ], 422);
        }
    }
}
```

When I hit the submit button on the popup form it shows me the HTML alert. I have also attached the screen shot of this alert: 
Here my data is not saving. I am kind of confused about this problem. Please help me regarding this problem. 
Your help will be highly appreciated!

Here is a screenshot of my alert: [image: Alert]

Comment: Someone in your Controller code is an error, so it's responding with the "Opps, there was an error" screen (that's the jumbled response your see; a mix of html/js/css). Check your Logs for the actual error (storage/logs/laravel.log)

Comment: Also, why are you refetching the User? You have them from `$user = Auth::guard()->user();`, so there shouldn't be any reason to call `$obj_user = User::find($user_id);` again; seems redundant.

Comment: can you please edit in my controller

Answer (score 0):

The question is if your javascript in within your blade.php file if it's not in your blade.php you can't use the blade syntax:

```
url: "{{ url('/changepassword') }}",
```

the bracers or only valid within the blade template area not in your js just replace it with this

```
url: "/changepassword",
```

Further add check if you get any data from your javascript like this in your controller method

```
dd($request->all());
```

If it does output your the data you are trying to sent your ajax works if not it does not.